# Несколько scrollIntoView не работают синхронно?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть 4 слайдера с цифрами. Для каждого элемента слайдера я использую scrollIntoView . По идеи все 4 слайдера должны прокручиваться синхронно , console.log отрабатывает у всех правильно и синхронно , но scrollIntoView работает только на последнем элементе , а все остальные слайдеры просто прокручиваются до конца после завершения прокручивания последнего слайдера. В чём проблема не пойму , помогите пожалуйста. Использую Vue3.

```
<template>
  <div class="timer_main">
    <div class="inputBlock">
      <input
        type="datetime-local"
        class="inputDateTime"
        v-model="inputDateTimeValue"
        step="1"
      />
      <button @click="startDateTimeCount" class="btnStart">Запустить</button>
    </div>
    <div class="day" ref="dayScroll">
      <span
        class="item"
        v-for="(day, index) in dateTimeLocal.day"
        :key="index"
        >{{ day }}</span
      >
    </div>
    <div>:</div>
    <div class="hour" ref="hourScroll">
      <span
        class="item"
        v-for="(hour, index) in dateTimeLocal.hour"
        :key="index"
        >{{ hour }}</span
      >
    </div>
    <div>:</div>
    <div class="minute" ref="minuteScroll">
      <span
        class="item"
        v-for="(minute, index) in dateTimeLocal.minute"
        :key="index"
        >{{ minute }}</span
      >
    </div>
    <div>:</div>
    <div class="second" ref="secondScroll">
      <span
        class="item"
        v-for="(second, index) in dateTimeLocal.second"
        :key="index"
        >{{ second }}</span
      >
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, reactive } from "vue";
export default {
  name: "Timer",
  setup() {
    const dateTimeLocal = reactive({
      day: ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
      hour: ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
      minute: ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
      second: ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
    });
   
    const inputDateTimeValue = ref(null);
    const dayScroll = ref(null);
    const hourScroll = ref(null);
    const minuteScroll = ref(null);
    const secondScroll = ref(null);
  
   const startTimer = () => {
      let a = 0;
      let aId = setInterval(() => {
        if (a == dateTimeLocal.day.length) {
          clearInterval(aId);
        } else {
          dayScroll.value.children[a].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
          console.log("Дни идут");
        }
        a++;
      }, 1000);

      let b = 0;
      let bId = setInterval(() => {
        if (b == dateTimeLocal.hour.length) {
          clearInterval(bId);
        } else {
          hourScroll.value.children[b].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
          console.log("Часы идут");
        }
        b++;
      }, 1000);

      let c = 0;
      let cId = setInterval(() => {
        if (c == dateTimeLocal.minute.length) {
          clearInterval(cId);
        } else {
          minuteScroll.value.children[c].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
          console.log("Минуты идут", minuteScroll.value.children[c]);
        }
        c++;
      }, 1000);

      let d = 0;
      let dId = setInterval(() => {
        if (d == dateTimeLocal.second.length) {
          clearInterval(dId);
        } else {
          secondScroll.value.children[d].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
          console.log("Секунды идут");
        }
        d++;
      }, 1000);
    };

    const startDateTimeCount = () => {
      startTimer();
    };

    return {
      dateTimeLocal,
      dayScroll,
      hourScroll,
      minuteScroll,
      secondScroll,
      startTimer,
      inputDateTimeValue,
      startDateTimeCount,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.timer_main {
  display: flex;
  font-family: var(--font-first);
  font-size: var(--font-big);
  color: var(--color-first);

  .inputBlock {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    display: flex;
    .inputDateTime,
    .btnStart {
      height: 100px;
      padding: 0 20px;
      margin: 100px 20px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      background: var(--color-first);
      color: var(--background-app);
      font-size: 50px;
    }
  }
  .day,
  .hour,
  .minute,
  .second {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    .item {
      scroll-snap-align: start;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scrollIntoView - выполняет прокрутку родителя для отображения элемента, на котором он вызван. Когда Вы вызываете его поочереди на нескольких элементах, то происходит прокрутка к последнему, т.к. он должен в конечном итоге быть видимым

Comment: Не совсем понял , как решить проблему.

Comment: в зависимости от того, что Вы хотите реализовать. Я так и не понял, зачем вы создаете 4 списка с значениями от 0 до 5. Возможно нужно "поиграться" с async await

Comment: Вы же видели в интернет магазинах таймер с временем окончания скидки. Вот тоже самое , только с анимацией в виде вертикального слайдера.  Анимация похожая на это https://codepen.io/glaubersampaio/pen/vOZbPx. В этих списках хранятся числа для слайдера для количество дней , часов, минут и секунд.

Comment: Если вкратце то мне нужно чтобы было 4 блока с цифрами которые будут крутиться одновременно от 5 до 0.

Comment: так что мешает сделать как в примере, что Вы привели, а не изобретать что-то со скроллами?